# Get object from LIst<> with minimal property count

Tags: c#

I have an object that is defined in this way:

```
class BFull
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public List<BPart> PartsList { get; set; }
    public bool Processed { get; set; }
}
```

In other method I have a list `List<BFull> Fulls` and I need to select a `BFull` with the lowest number of `BPart` in it from `Fulls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use...

```
BFull minBFull = Fulls.OrderBy(x => x.PartsList.Count).First();
```

if you want all with the min-count:

```
IEnumerable<BFull> minBFulls = Fulls.GroupBy(x => x.PartsList.Count).OrderBy(g => g.Key).First();
```